# PDO BindValue doesn't work - execute returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, bindvalue

I got a big issue with pdo, noone seems to be able to help me with - so I decided to ask you guys :-)

```
try {
    $links = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE visible=:visible AND access<=:access AND category=:category ORDER BY orderNum ASC");
    $links->bindValue(':visible',$first,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $links->bindValue(':access',$second,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $links->bindValue(':category',$third,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $links->execute();
    print_r($asdf);
    print_r($database->errorInfo());
    print_r($links->errorInfo());
    while($row = $links->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Database-Connection works perfectly, the errorInfo()'s both return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

Now, this code somehow doesn't get any $row's. But if I would replace the prepare statement with the following lines:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM woody_sidebar WHERE visible=$first AND access<=$second AND category=$third ORDER BY orderNum ASC";
$links = $database->prepare($sql);
```

(and remove the bindValue-statements) the code works like charm!

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, because there is no error thrown at all - does anybody of you know anything I could try?

Thanks

Comment: It works even without quotes around category? In bindValue(), you're saying that category is a string.

Comment: Actually not - wrote that line just to show that without bindValue() the execution works perfect and forgot the quotes in the example.
The actual sql-string is:
     `SELECT * FROM \`woody_sidebar\` WHERE \`visible\`=$firstNumber AND \`access\`<=$secondNumber AND \`category\`='$thirdString' ORDER BY \`orderNum\` ASC `

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$links = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE visible=:visible AND access<=:access AND category=:category ORDER BY orderNum ASC");
$links->bindValue(':visible',$first,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$links->bindValue(':access',$second,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$links->bindValue(':category',$third,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

to this:

> In the second query your table name is `woody_sidebar` but you have `aTable` and $third is a `INT` and can be passed as a `PDO::PARAM_INT`

```
$links = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM woody_sidebar WHERE visible=:visible AND access<=:access AND category=:category ORDER BY orderNum ASC");
$links->bindValue(':visible',$first,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$links->bindValue(':access',$second,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$links->bindValue(':category',$third,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Not just tables names differ in first and second query, but variables names too...

Comment: And accordingly to name $thirdString - third params should be string, i think so...

Comment: @holzers you got some advance?

Comment: i think we should ask author of this question about it)

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is your table name.

Try this instead

```
try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM woody_sidebar WHERE visible=:visible AND access<=:access AND category=:category ORDER BY orderNum ASC";
    $links = $database->prepare($sql);
    $links->bindValue(':visible', $first, PDO::PARAM_INT); // assuming this is an integer
    $links->bindValue(':access', $second, PDO::PARAM_INT); // assuming this is an integer
    $links->bindValue(':category', $third, PDO::PARAM_STR); // assuming this is an text string or date
    $links->execute();
    print_r($asdf);
    print_r($database->errorInfo());
    print_r($links->errorInfo());
    while($row = $links->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```